# How to invert colors in Safari pages on macbook?

Tags: macos, safari, accessibility, safari-extensions

Any extension for the browser? I only want to invert safari's colors, not of the entire system.

Comment: Maybe you mean:
SystemPreferences->Accessibility->Display->Invert Colors LexS

Comment: That's the effect they want to get, but they want it to only happen on Safari windows, not the entire screen.

Answer (score 6):

Switch to reader view and then you can use the text settings to the right of the search bar to invert colors:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

From here

> According to Apple, you can change the colors of its Safari Web
>   browser by using Cascading Style Sheets (CSS). Many websites offer
>   free CSS templates for download (see Resources for some examples). You
>   must have a CSS saved onto your computer before you can change the
>   colors or style of your Safari browser.

Read more : http://www.ehow.com/how_6527587_change-colors-safari-browser.html

Example:

For example, to override a website using colored text on a colored background and set it to black text on a white background, you could add these styles:

```
body {

 color:black !important;

 background:white !important;

 }
```

How to [Add a Style Sheet using extensions](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/AddingStyles/AddingStyles.html)

Or use a software project that does this, like [Stylish](http://sobolev.us/stylish/)